# How to create User Log-in for HBase?

Tags: mysql, linux, hadoop, salesforce

How can i create user log-in for  Hbase.  I am trying log-in like Mysql(Eg: mysql -u root -pPass).

Can i able to create these kind of Log-in for the HBase, is that doable ?
Please let me know on this.

Am planning to migrate Data from Salesforce to HBase, Please recommend me an easy way to replicate data from different resources on Hadoop Platform

Thanks & Regards
Kiran Haridas

Answer (score 0):

in hbase you are not able to to create the user base auth permission but you can add HBase Authorization like below link . you can also configure it according to the name nodes and data nodes.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_8_3.html